# gcloud.app.deploy Error Response: [9] Application startup error: public@1.0.0 start /app node app.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am curious about an error message I received.

**the environment**

- Google app engine
- Nodejs
- Flex environment
- no express server installed

**the setup**

- app.yaml contains standard info
- server.js was created but is empty at
  the moment
- app.js was created but is empty at the moment

**the error**

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
>
> Application startup error:
>
> public@1.0.0 start /app
>
> node app.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with GCP Support.

There was an internal issue affecting Google App Engine Memcache from 2018-10-23T00:24 to 2018-10-23T02:16 US/Pacific. **The issue is fixed now** and you should be able to deploy correctly by now.

Further investigations of the issue will be made to improve the systems and prevent this issue in the future.