# Unable to deploy php72 in gae standard env - exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm moving from php55 to php72 and have a big problem deploying now. I have a big exclude list and thought the problem is that I have too many files (I had to include some classes with composer). I made a bigger list of files and directories and I only deploy about 7000 files. 10000 are the limit.

- I tried with a bigger machine type in app.yaml ( F2 instead of F1 ) that
  doesn't help
- Do I have a problem with the time it takes to upload all
  files? I don't know
- Why is a tar file created? Is there a way to
  suppress this?

upload is done with a mac and the following commands. First line removed all files which make problems too which worked normaly and the aren't uploaded:

```
find . -name "Icon?" -print0 -exec rm {} \;
gcloud app deploy --project MyProjectName-dev --verbosity debug app.yaml cron.yaml dos.yaml
```

The error I get is something weird:

`Starting Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetcher": Fetching manifest gs://staging.xxxxxxxxx-dev.appspot.com/ae/xxxxxxxxxx-8b1b-4aa6-b6c5-xxxxxxxxx/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Processing 6765 files.
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetcher": Status: SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetcher": Started: 2018-10-24T16:54:28Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Completed: 2018-10-24T16:54:41Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Requested workers: 200
Step #0 - "fetcher": Actual workers: 200
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total files: 6765
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total retries: 131
Step #0 - "fetcher": GCS timeouts: 129
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB downloaded: 909.85 MiB
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB/s throughput: 68.62 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetcher": Time for manifest: 262.79 ms
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total time: 13.58 s
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetcher"
Starting Step #1 - "builder"
.... much more here and on the end I get:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO gzip_tar_runtime_package took 33 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO Finished gzipping tarfile.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO Building app layer took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO tar_runtime_package tar -pcvf /tmp/tmpmwmv3C.tar --transform flags=r;s,^,/.gaeconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO tar_runtime_package took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO Building app layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 46 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR tar_runtime_package tar -pcvf /tmp/tmpmwmv3C.tar --transform flags=r;s,^,/.gaeconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/php72_app_builder:php72_7_2_8_20181012_RC00" failed: exit status 1`

Comment: `[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory` seems to suggest you're running out of memory (RAM)..

Comment: Hi Devon, I don't have the possibility to add more memory because this is done at google and not locally. That was the first thing I thought too.

Comment: Is this happening today? There was an internal issue a couple of days before in GAE and memcache, this seems related. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946483/gcloud-app-deploy-error-response-9-application-startup-error-public1-0-0-st/52949472#52949472)

Comment: Ups, I tried this morning and it worked fine, but I've removed nearly half of the files for the upload. Thanks a lot this helps me. I'll come back if the problem still exisist with the full project.

Comment: OK. It doesn't work. with 5700 Files it's working, but with 6'800 not. Does anybody have another idea what the problem may be?

Comment: This might be a stretch, but is the Cloud Build API enabled?

Comment: Cloud Build API is enabled for this project. I can deploy if I don't upload all files, but If I upload all, it still crashes with low memory warning...